How can I check memory leak in a .NET MAUI application using Android Studio and perfview?
How can I check memory lek in a .NET MAUI application using Android Studio and perfview?

Didn't we get gcdump for mono already?

I am using the .NET 8 version, but I am still facing an issue retrieving the process ID for the Android platform.
